# Array required, but String found

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I want to build a copy of code that involves method and array. My intention is to display a date that will be entered by the user. But the `array required, but string found` error appeared. This is part of my code:

```
public class Reservation{
    public static Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String[] date=new String[5];
    public static int arraylength=5;
    public static int index;

    public static void main (String[] args){
      start();
    }

    //this is the method where the date will be entered
    public static void register(){
        for(index=0;index<date.length;index++){
            System.out.print("Enter the date of reservation(DD/MM/YY): ");
            date[index]=input.nextLine();
        }
    }

    // this is the method where date will be display
    public static void display(String date, int index,int arraylength){
        for(index=0;index<arraylength;index++){
            System.out.println("The date ["+index+"]: "+date[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `display` method, you provide `String` object and try iterating through it as it was an array?

Answer (score 3):

You are using `date[index]` but variable `date` is defined as `String date` in the method parameter. It is not an array, to define array type you should use `String[] date`.

```
// this is the method where date will be display
public static void display(String[] date, int index)
{
   System.out.println("The date ["+index+"]: "+date[index]);
}
```

Comment: i see...so what should i do?sorry im completely new in java

Comment: if you pass an array as parameter, then change the parameter type, otherwise change the method code.

Answer (score 3):

Error is here

```
 public static void display(String date, int index,int arraylength)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As you have passed an simple string in the function and you are trying to access as date[index]

Also, your local and global variable have same name, hence Local Variable get priority. So it is considering date as simple string variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use static field that you defined as method argument which is in conflict, so change it as below:

```
System.out.println("The date ["+index+"]: "+Reservation.date[index]);
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or change the method definition to something like:

```
public static void display(String aDate, int index,int arraylength)
```

Comment: i try to put Reservation.date[index]....all clear but i receives a new problem...the code is looping the date question...before this it will ask the next question...e.g How many person etc...this is just part of my code